# whenever i close my laptop lid wifi gets disabled and i need to restart my laptop

Tags: networking, wireless

whenever i close my laptop my wifi hardware gets disabled and i need to use an ethernet cable and in order to re enable wireless wifi i need to restart my laptop
i have an hp pavillion notebook from 2016 if that helps with anything

Comment: We have no OS & release details, but at worst I'd expect a restart of NetworkManager would resolve the issue, but I'd start with what you're using (details of your actual wifi chipset may also help)

Comment: oh shoot im using ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
and how do i restart network manager?

Comment: i belive my wifi hardware is a logitech inc. unifying reciver
im sorry that might be totally wrong